# How to detect browser and show video according to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show a video according to browser means if some one open page in chrome then chrome.mp4 should be play and so on.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="application/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
<script>
var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;   // At least IE6
if(isFirefox==true)
{
    $("#my").html("<embed src='mozilla.mp4'></embed>");
}

</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="my"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my current code. . its not working

Comment: You should probably being this server side no?

Comment: How to detect the browser from server side?

Comment: Generally browser detection is a difficult  and bad thing to do. Consider just letting the user chose the browser/movie. Other that that what exactly is the problem? In which browers doesn't it work? Ist there an error in the console? Did you step through the code and find the part that doesn't work?

Comment: document.getElementById(...) is null   its saying this . .

Comment: server side using user agent header

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr.js to detect what browser can use what type of attributes and so on.